# How to retrieve a selected value from a list box?

Tags: selenium, listbox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

HTML Content:

```
<select id="modalNewUser-body-information-timeZone" class="span12 ng-valid ng-dirty" ng-options="timezone for timezone in timezoneList" ng-model="newUser().timeZone" uid="timeZone" name="timezone">
    <option selected="" value="">-- Select One --</option>
    <option value="0">AST</option>
    <option value="1">EST</option>
    <option value="2">CST</option>
    <option value="3">MST</option>
    <option value="4">PST</option>
    <option value="5">YST</option>
    <option value="6">HST</option>
</select>
```

suppose I have selected 'EST' from the list box How can I retrieve it?
I am not able to retrieve with getFirstSelectedOption().getText()

Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("modalNewUser-body-information-timeZone")));
select.selectByVisibleText("EST");
String timeZone = select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that you can only use Select elements when there is actually a 'select' tag. Often times, things that look like drop down boxes don't truly behave like Select elements. What if you tried to get the text this way (I'm C# here, but Java just has different capital letters for this, I believe):

```
string timeZone = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@value = '1']")).Text;
```

expected return: "EST"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("#modalNewUser-body-information-timeZone option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code provide by you is working fine for me.

Could you please update your selenium version and try again?

Following is the tested code:

```
Select select = new Select(abhiDriver.findElement(By.id("modalNewUser-body-information-timeZone")));
select.selectByVisibleText("EST");
String timeZone = select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
System.out.println(timeZone);
```